# Extra characters at PHP output when CloudFlare used

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<div style="margin-left:100px;">
    <table>
        <?php for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
        {
            echo "\n".'<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>';
        }?>
    </table>
</div>
```

The above script, when run, reflects the following at the browser:

```
<div style="margin-left:100px;">
    <table>
        <tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
        .
        . (8 times)
        .
    </table>
</div>
```

No surprises, this was as expected. But the following output rendered at the browser was something unexpected.

> ```
>                >>>>>>>>
>                 data1   data2
>                 data1   data2
>                 .
>                 .(8 times)
>                 .
> ```

I really cannot figure out where the extra characters `>>>>>>>>` came from. One thing I can suspect here is [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com/) (I use to speed up my website) which adds javascripts to optimize my website. But I am really not sure. Please help.

This is what I can see through firebug:

```
<div style="margin-left:100px;">
     &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;
    <table>
        <tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
        .
        . (8 times)
        .
    </table>
</div>
```

One thing is little more surprising here. There are 8 rows in the table and there are exactly 8 `>`s

Comment: I suppose you have somewhere an extra `>` in a closing tag inside the loop. The code you posted is exactly that one you're using?

Comment: @Sara, `\n` needs to wrap the code in the source code. No need to have a `<br>` between `<tr>` (it would also generates invalid markup)

Comment: I have added \n for the html source to be readable. That is not a problem

Comment: @ahmedtabrez. if you look at the source code of the page via firebug/firefox you see exactly the symbol `<`?

Comment: `<tr>' will break rows rite? no need of `\n`

Comment: @Sara: sorry, no - `\n` formats text (the html-source code), `<br/>` is a html-tag that the browser interprets (and not valid before a `<tr>`). @ahmedtabrez: did you look at the html source code after CloudFlare did it's magic?

Comment: I have updated the question please take a look.

Comment: &lt; is ASCII for less than sign and in your output there's clearly a greater than sign which is &gt; in ASCII, that's weird. your code is correct and i am getting result as expected, try to find "&gt;" or "&lt;" in your code.

Comment: I am sorry I messed it up. I have edited the question

Comment: did you try it without the \n? the only reason i could guess according to your code is some strange encoding problem with the linebreak, windows, linux and CloudFlare. The code as such is ok, the reason for this strange behaviour has to be somewhere else. Maybe try to contact CloudFlare with this question?

Comment: What does your view source say? (ignore firebug for the moment)

Comment: view source reflects code without &gt;'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really cannot figure out where the extra characters >>>>>>>> came from.

We most likely wouldn't be the cause of this. One easy way to test if CloudFlare is causing an issue or not is to temporarily deactivate CloudFlare (Settings -> Pause CloudFlare). If the problem is still there with us off (wait about 5 minutes before checking), then the issue is directly on your server.

Comment: are you an employee at cloudflare?